# Trying to understand deep RNN weights

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to understand what weights are trained for RNN. For a simple RNN with 1 layer it is easy to understand. For example if the input shape for the time step is [50, 3], there are 3 weights to train for each feature, plus the bias for the weight and plus the weight for the input state. But I am struggling to understand how the paramtres becomes 12, 21, 32 as the number of RNN increases. Thanks for any guidance.

```
model = Sequential([
    SimpleRNN(1, return_sequences = False, input_shape = [50, 3]),    # 3 features and 1 per Wx and Wy
    Dense(1) 
])


model.summary()

model2 = Sequential([
    SimpleRNN(2, return_sequences = False, input_shape = [50, 3]),    
    Dense(1) # last do not neeed the return sequencies
])

model2.summary()


model3 = Sequential([
    SimpleRNN(3, return_sequences = False, input_shape = [50, 3]),   
    Dense(1) # last do not neeed the return sequencies
])

model3.summary()


model4 = Sequential([
    SimpleRNN(4, return_sequences = False, input_shape = [50, 3]),  
    Dense(1) # last do not neeed the return sequencies
])
```

```
Model: "sequential_20"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
simple_rnn_22 (SimpleRNN)    (None, 1)                 5         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_18 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 2         
=================================================================
Total params: 7
Trainable params: 7
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "sequential_21"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
simple_rnn_23 (SimpleRNN)    (None, 2)                 12        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_19 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 3         
=================================================================
Total params: 15
Trainable params: 15
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "sequential_22"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
simple_rnn_24 (SimpleRNN)    (None, 3)                 21        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_20 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 4         
=================================================================
Total params: 25
Trainable params: 25
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "sequential_23"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
simple_rnn_25 (SimpleRNN)    (None, 4)                 32        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_21 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 5         
=================================================================
Total params: 37
Trainable params: 37
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your model 2:

```py
model2 = Sequential([
    SimpleRNN(2, return_sequences = False, input_shape = [50, 3]),    
    Dense(1) # last do not neeed the return sequencies
])
```

The image below shows you the weights to one of the neurons (5 weights) and you will have 1 bias. So each neuron has 6 parameter and the total parameters count will be 6*2 = 12.

[image]

The formula for your example will be:
`h * (3 + h) + h`
where `(3 + h)` is the number of weights for each neuron and the last `h` adds the biases to the parameters

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes sense now.

Comment: Are each of the 'neurons' an individual RNN unit that each deal with one input, or are the inputs all concatenated into a single input for a single RNN unit? I'm so confused and most of the explanations online miss a lot of this out.

Comment: @Matt I don't understand your question clearly but I hope this helps: RNNs are layers not single neurons. for example in the image above inside the *current timestep* (red circles) is a layer of RNN which gets a layer of input (blue circles) and its previous state (gray circles). Actually gray circles are not individual things. They are red circles in the last timestep